# Calculate mean and variance of conditional sum of Gammas

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Find $Mean(Z)$ and $Var(Z)$, where:

$Z = \begin{cases}W + X_1 & \text{if } W \leq c \\ W + X_2 & \text{if } W > c \end{cases}$

where $\quad W \sim \Gamma(k_0, \theta_0), \quad X_1 \sim \Gamma(k_1, \theta_1), \quad X_2 \sim \Gamma(k_2, \theta_2)$ are independent, and $c$ is a constant $> 0$.

My code in mathematica using mathStatica is as follows:

```
f=((w^(Subscript[k, 0]-1)*Exp[-w/Subscript[\[Theta], 0]])/(Gamma[Subscript[k, 0]]*Subscript[\[Theta], 0]^(Subscript[k, 0])))*((Subscript[x, 1]^(Subscript[k, 1]-1)*Exp[-Subscript[x, 1]/Subscript[\[Theta], 1]])/(Gamma[Subscript[k, 1]]*Subscript[\[Theta], 1]^(Subscript[k, 1])))*((Subscript[x, 2]^(Subscript[k, 2]-1)*Exp[-Subscript[x, 2]/Subscript[\[Theta], 2]])/(Gamma[Subscript[k, 2]]*Subscript[\[Theta], 2]^(Subscript[k, 2])));
domain[f]={{w,-Infinity,Infinity},{Subscript[x,1],-Infinity,Infinity} ,{Subscript[x,2],-Infinity,Infinity}} && {Subscript[k, 0]>0,Subscript[k, 1]>0,Subscript[k, 2]>0,Subscript[\[Theta], 0]>0,Subscript[\[Theta], 1]>0,Subscript[\[Theta], 2] >0,g >0};
z=\[Piecewise]  w+Subscript[x,1] w<=c  w+Subscript[x,2] w>c;
mean=Expect[z,f]
var=Var[z,f]
```

However, mathematica (Mathstatica) is unable to calculate the mean and variance of this expression.
Is there a better way to calculate the mean and variance of Z?

The following Monte carlo simulation shows:

```
Ddata=RandomReal[GammaDistribution[121,0.09],100000];
T1data=RandomReal[GammaDistribution[100,0.01],100000];
T2data=RandomReal[GammaDistribution[5.76,0.2083],100000];
Adata=MapThread[If[#1<12,#1+#2,#1+#3]&,{Ddata,T1data,T2data}];
N[Mean[Adata]]
N[Sqrt[Variance[Adata]]]
```

mean=11.91 and variance 1.10

Comment: Start by removing `Subscript` from your variable names, which leads to all sort of troubles and makes your code unreadable. Then use `GammaDistribution`  `Distributed`, `Probability` and `TransformedDistribution`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define distributions and calculate probabilities, for instance of the condition $w < c$.

```
Probability[
 w < c
 , Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
 ]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{1 - Gamma[k0, c/th0]/Gamma[k0], c > 0}}, 0]
> ```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Once distributions are defined you can easily calculate [`Mean`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html) and [`Variance`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Variance.html).

```
Mean[
 TransformedDistribution[
  w + x1,
  {
   Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
   , Distributed[x1, GammaDistribution[k1, th1]]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> k0 th0 + k1 th1
> ```

```
Variance[
 TransformedDistribution[
  w + x1,
  {
   Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
   , Distributed[x1, GammaDistribution[k1, th1]]
   }
  ]
 ]
```

> ```
> k0 th0^2 + k1 th1^2
> ```

Your distribution is conditional so you need to incorporate that condition using [`Conditioned`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Conditioned.html)

```
Mean@TransformedDistribution[
  Conditioned[w + x1, w > c],
  {
   Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
   , Distributed[x1, GammaDistribution[k1, th1]]
   }
  ]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{k0*th0 + k1*th1, c <= 0}}, k1*th1 + (th0*Gamma[1 + k0, c/th0])/Gamma[k0, c/th0]]
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with [`Piecewise`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Piecewise.html)

```
Mean@TransformedDistribution[
  Piecewise[{{w + x1, w > c}, {w + x2, w < c}}],
  {
   Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
   , Distributed[x1, GammaDistribution[k1, th1]]
   , Distributed[x2, GammaDistribution[k2, th2]]
   }]
```

> ```
> Piecewise[{{k0*th0 + k1*th1, c <= 0}}, ((k0*th0 + k2*th2)*Gamma[k0] + (k1*th1 - k2*th2)*Gamma[k0, c/th0])/Gamma[k0]]
> ```
>
> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Assuming[And @@ Table[i > 0, {i, {c, k0, k1, k2, th0, th1, th2}}],
 FullSimplify[
  Variance@TransformedDistribution[
    Piecewise[{{w + x1, w > c}, {w + x2, w < c}}],
    {
     Distributed[w, GammaDistribution[k0, th0]]
     , Distributed[x1, GammaDistribution[k1, th1]]
     , Distributed[x2, GammaDistribution[k2, th2]]
     }]
  ]]
```

> ```
> (1/(Gamma[k0]^2))((k2 th2^2 + 
>  k0 th0 (th0 + 2 k1 th1 - 2 k2 th2)) Gamma[
> k0]^2 + (k1 th1 - k2 th2) Gamma[k0, c/
> th0] (-2 th0 Gamma[1 + k0] + (-k1 th1 + k2 th2) Gamma[k0, c/
>    th0]) + Gamma[
> k0] (2 th0 (-k1 th1 + k2 th2) Gamma[
>    1 + k0] + (k1 (1 + k1) th1^2 - 
>     2 k1 k2 th1 th2 + (-1 + k2) k2 th2^2) Gamma[k0, c/th0] + 
>  2 th0 (k1 th1 - k2 th2) Gamma[1 + k0, c/th0]))
> ```

```
N[
 ((k0 th0 + k2 th2) Gamma[k0] + (k1 th1 - k2 th2) Gamma[k0, c/th0])/
  Gamma[k0] /.
  {
   k0 -> 121
   , th0 -> 0.09
   , k1 -> 100
   , th1 -> 0.01
   , k2 -> 5.76
   , th2 -> 0.2083
   , c -> 12
   }]
```

> ```
> 12.0634
> ```

```
(k2 th2^2 Gamma[
   k0]^2 - (th0 Gamma[1 + k0] + (k1 th1 - k2 th2) Gamma[k0, c/
     th0])^2 + 
 Gamma[k0] (th0^2 Gamma[
      2 + k0] + (k1 (1 + k1) th1^2 - 
       2 k1 k2 th1 th2 + (-1 + k2) k2 th2^2) Gamma[k0, c/th0] + 
    2 th0 (k1 th1 - k2 th2) Gamma[1 + k0, c/th0]))/Gamma[k0]^2
     /. {
       k0 -> 121
       , th0 -> 0.09
       , k1 -> 100
       , th1 -> 0.01
       , k2 -> 5.76
       , th2 -> 0.2083
       , c -> 12
       }]
```

> ```
> 1.1153203656002
> ```